# Set the setState to the searched books array to made it back to the blank array in case of invalid query

Tags: javascript, reactjs

for a React project I have to setState the searched books array back to the blank array in case of invalid query, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem at the moment.

This is my code:

```
search_books = (val) => {
    if (val.length !== 0 ) {
      BooksAPI.search( val, 10 ).then((books) => {
        if (books.length > 0 ) {
          books = this.changeBookShelf(books)
          this.setState(() => {
            return {Books: books}
          })
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({Books: [], query: ''})
    }
}
```

and this is the full code in case you'll need it:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import * as BooksAPI from '../BooksAPI'
import Book from './Book'
import {PropTypes} from 'prop-types'

class BookSearch extends Component {
  state = {
    Books: [],
    query: ''
  }

  static propTypes = {
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    myBooks: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  }

  handleChange = ( event ) => {
    var value = event.target.value
    this.setState(() => {
      return {query: value}
    })
    this.search_books(value)
  }

  changeBookShelf = ( books ) => {
    let all_Books = this.props.myBooks
    for ( let book of books ) {
      book.shelf = "none"
    }

    for ( let book of books ) {
      for ( let b of all_Books ) {
        if ( b.id === book.id ) {
          book.shelf = b.shelf
        }
      }
    }
    return books
  }

  search_books = (val) => {
    if (val.length !== 0 ) {
      BooksAPI.search( val, 10 ).then((books) => {
        if (books.length > 0 ) {
          books = this.changeBookShelf(books)
          this.setState(() => {
            return {Books: books}
          })
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({Books: [], query: ''})
    }
  }

  add_book = ( book, shelf ) => {
    this.props.onChange( book, shelf )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-books">
        <div className="search-books-bar">
          <Link to='/' className="close-search">Close</Link>
          <div className="search-books-input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search by title or author" value={this.state.query} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="search-books-results">
          <ol className="books-grid">
            {this.state.query.length > 0 && this.state.Books.map((book, index) => (<Book book={book} key={index} onUpdate={(shelf) => {
              this.add_book( book, shelf )
            }}/>))}
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BookSearch;
```

It's the last step but I can't figure out how to make the search launching an error if an invalid query is written in the search bar.

Comment: Add a third state property, `error` for example that you set in such cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're properly setting it to an empty array when there is no query, but forgetting to do so when there is a query string but no matching books. You just need to add an else statement in your .then function:

```
search_books = (val) => {
if (val.length !== 0 ) {
  BooksAPI.search( val, 10 ).then((books) => {
    if (books.length > 0 ) {
      books = this.changeBookShelf(books)
      this.setState(() => {
        return {Books: books}
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({Books: []})
    }
  })
} else {
  this.setState({Books: [], query: ''})
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works very well. I didn't think about it!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an error object to the `state` and use it to render a message:

```
  state = {
    Books: [],
    query: '',
    error: {
      isError: false,
      message: ''
    }
  }
```

Inside your search logic you can change the `error` object:

```
  search_books = (val) => {
    if (val.length !== 0 ) {
      BooksAPI.search( val, 10 ).then((books) => {
        if (books.length > 0 ) {
          books = this.changeBookShelf(books)
          this.setState(() => {
            return {Books: books, error: {isError: false, message: ''}}
          })
        } else{
            this.setState(() => {
              return {Books: [], error: {isError:true, message:"No books"}}
            })
          }
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({Books: [], query: '', {isError:true, message:"No books"}})
    }
  }
```

In your `render` method you can check the `error` object and display an error if needed:

```
render(){
  // ...
  error.isError && <div>{error.message}</div>
  //...
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help!